# How do you pull data from one sheet to 3 other sheets based on specific column values?

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I would like to know how can one pull data with VBA from one sheet to the other 3 sheets based on the value one column has.

For Example.

You have 4 Sheets. Tree1, Tree2, Tree3, Data

Tree1, Tree2, and Tree3 have different columns of data.
Sheet 4 which is called data has different columns of data but the 1 column's values are "TreeOne", "TreeTwo", and "TreeThree".

I would like to formula to pull from the datasheet each respective tree's data based on that one column from the Datasheet.

```
 Example of the "Data" Sheet

 |Colour| Bark| Hight| Season| Specie|
 | Brown| Soft| 10   | Summer| Tree 1|
 | Brown| hard| 12   | Winter| Tree 2|
 | Brown| hard| 14   | Summer| Tree 1|
 | Brown| soft| 12   | Winter| Tree 3|
 | Brown| hard| 11   | Summer| Tree 2|
```

So the query should pull from the "Data" Sheet into each specific sheet based on the "Specie" column.

```
 Example of the "TreeOne" Sheet

 |Colour| Bark| Hight| Season| Specie|
 | Brown| Soft| 10   | Summer| Tree 1|
 | Brown| hard| 14   | Summer| Tree 1|


 Example of the "TreeTwo" Sheet

 |Colour| Bark| Hight| Season| Specie| 
 | Brown| hard| 12   | Winter| Tree 2|
 | Brown| hard| 11   | Summer| Tree 2|


  Example of the "TreeThree" Sheet

 |Colour| Bark| Hight| Season| Specie|
 | Brown| soft| 12   | Winter| Tree 3|
```

As you can see the VBA query looks at the "Specie" Column and based on the specific species, pulls all the data of that Species to the sheet indicated for that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update Criteria Worksheets (`AutoFilter`)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateSpeciesWorksheets()
    
    Const sName As String = "Data"
    Const sCol As Long = 5
    Const CriteriaList As String = "Tree 1,Tree 2,Tree 3"
    Const dNamesList As String = "TreeOne,TreeTwo,TreeThree"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim Criteria() As String: Criteria = Split(CriteriaList, ",")
    Dim dNames() As String: dNames = Split(dNamesList, ",")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    If sws.AutoFilterMode Then sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Dim svrg As Range
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 0 To UBound(Criteria) ' or 'UBound(dNames)'
        
        ' Attempt to reference the destination current ('n') worksheet.
        On Error Resume Next
            Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dNames(n))
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If dws Is Nothing Then ' worksheet doesn't exist
            Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
            dws.Name = dNames(n)
        Else ' worksheet exists
            dws.UsedRange.Clear ' clear previous values
        End If
        
        ' Reference the source visible (filtered) range (headers included).
        srg.AutoFilter sCol, Criteria(n)
        Set svrg = srg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        sws.AutoFilterMode = False ' remove the filter
        
        ' Copy the source visible range to the destination worksheet.
        svrg.Copy dws.Range("A1")
        
'        ' Copy the column widths.
'        With dws.Range("A1")
'            srg.Copy
'            .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
'            .Parent.Activate
'            .Select
'        End With
        
        Set dws = Nothing ' necessary to work correctly on the next iteration
    
    Next n
        
    sws.Activate
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
    MsgBox "Species worksheets updated.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I have used the code in the actual sheet with the data and it does not work, I should only update the 4 lines starting with "Const" to adjust for current data I am using. It gives me compile error.

Comment: You have concluded correctly. Which line is throwing the error and which message does it show? And what exactly did you put in the line?

Comment: Feel free to download [my working file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jOA_3lyoUDvFuO4ffbYbmfkxhqaXxs9G/view?usp=sharing) from Google Drive.

Comment: Is there a way I can send you the file personally to see if your code is done correctly?

Comment: There is an email on my profile page. Just click on my name. Let me know when you have sent it.

Comment: Hi, I have just emailed you the sheet called SSI, Thank you :)

Comment: I received the file. It has little to do with the question you posted. I don't feel like writing and checking those twenty letter worksheet names to a comma-separated list. You're on your own. Nice try though.

Comment: It is the same though, 1 sheet has all the data and the other sheets are to products. But none the less, thank you for reaching out :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub ClearData(rngSpecies As Range)
    Dim uniqueSpecie As String
    Dim rngSpecie As Range
    Dim aux As Long
    
    For Each rngSpecie In rngSpecies
        If InStr(1, uniqueSpecie, rngSpecie.Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            On Error Resume Next
            aux = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(rngSpecie.Value).Index
            If Err.Number = 9 Then
                rngSpecie.Activate
                MsgBox "Worksheet '" & rngSpecie.Value & "' doesn't exist. Error in cell " & rngSpecie.Address
                Exit Sub
            End If
            uniqueSpecie = uniqueSpecie & rngSpecie.Value & ";"
        End If
    Next
    If uniqueSpecie <> "" Then
        uniqueSpecie = Left(uniqueSpecie, Len(uniqueSpecie) - 1)
    End If
    
    Dim aSpecies As Variant
    aSpecies = Split(uniqueSpecie, ";")
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(aSpecies) To UBound(aSpecies)
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(aSpecies(i)).Range("A:E").EntireColumn.ClearContents
        'Set the header
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(aSpecies(i)).Range("A1:E1").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Range("A1:E1").Value
    Next i
End Sub

Sub CopyData()
    Dim shtData As Worksheet
    Set shtData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data")
    'Clear old data ans sets the header
    ClearData shtData.Range("E2:E" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Range("E2").End(xlDown).Row)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long 'i = actual row in data sheet, j = new row in species sheet
    i = 2
    
    Do While shtData.Cells(i, 5) <> "" 'species
        j = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(CStr(shtData.Cells(i, 5))).Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        'this does the trick
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(CStr(shtData.Cells(i, 5))).Range("A" & j & ":E" & j).Value = _
                     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Range("A" & i & ":E" & i).Value
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```